# How to scale larger images in android?

Tags: android, image-processing

i am using following code to download and display images in android

its works many time but some times it gives me error for larger images any one guide me what is the solutions to this problem?

LogCat

```
10-12 18:55:52.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-30
10-12 18:55:52.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-12 18:55:52.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:344)
10-12 18:55:52.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434):     at com.Utils.ImageLoader.loadImageFromUrl(ImageLoader.java:83)
10-12 18:55:52.283: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434):     at com.Utils.ImageLoader$2.run(ImageLoader.java:44)
```

ImageLoading Code

```
public static Bitmap loadImageFromUrl(String url) {

        Bitmap bm;
        try {  

                URL aURL = new URL(url);  
                URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection(); 

                conn.connect();  
                InputStream is = null;
                try
                {
                 is= conn.getInputStream();  
                }catch(IOException e)
                {
                     return null;
                }

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);  
                BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis,null,options);

                bis.close();  
                is.close();  

           } catch (IOException e) {  
            return null;
           }  
        return  Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,100,100,true);  // error here

    }
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you want to create a scaled bitmap since you pick the sampleSize?Why don't you lower , raise the inSampleSize andyou get the desired bitmap without call createScaledBitmap the first place

Comment: sorry i dont understand what you saying..

Comment: why you call createScaledBitmap to get the bitmap and not decodeStream?

Comment: because i need small sized scaled image instead of that i am getting in decodestream which is high resolution image.

Comment: your imageView can handle that for u. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Comment: i wouldn't trust createScaledBitmap if i didn't know how it works. It maybe has problem upscaling or... I would look to the code or just use scaleType to the imageView